# What are the usb ports for on Cisco routers?

Tags: cisco, hardware, router

Most of the new routers I've seen have (2) usb ports. What are they for?

Answer (score 2):

New Cisco routers and switches have also usb ports for console access :

[image: cisco_2960s]

You can see here two usb ports. On the left is a usb-host port, which is used like Mark said for flash drives or strong auth, and on the right, in the blue square is a usb slave port, which will appear to the computer as a usb to serial device.

Answer (score 1):

They are used for Flash Modules and eToken Hardware, [amongst other things](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/access/2800/hardware/notes/mithril.html).